# WSO2 API Manager: Can Consumer Key & Consumer Secret be exposed

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 api manager and client application is a angular application.I have an application in the store correspodning to the angular application in the API Manager store . To get the bearer token , the base 64 encoded consumer key and secret of this consumer application  has to be passed from angular .
As of now , i kept it in angular and its fine.But want to know if its safe.
If i keep this in angular , any one can see it if they check the source of the application ? Is it desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the client key is a public value, but the client secret shouldn't be exposed to the public. For client-side applications, you can use implicit grant type, which will require Client Key only. But this grant type has its own limitations.

Read [this](https://labs.hybris.com/2012/06/05/oauth2-the-implicit-flow-aka-as-the-client-side-flow/) for more details.